# Phyloseq: swap row.names in otu_table

Tags: r, phyloseq

I have reasons to believe that the sample name of two sequences V4 16SrRNA were swapped.
In my case thay are the row.names of the otu_table.

Since I already have the phyloseq object how do I change these names to correspond to the true sequence?

Thank you in advance
Cristina Paulo

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

Answer (score 0):

This is a bit of a work-around, but you can merge a metadata map with your samples correct orientation into phyloseq. You can make a metadata map in excel, where the name of your files is the first column (no label for the first column) and the sample names you want corresponding to those files is the second column (the column labeled Sample_Name in the picture). You can add other information about your samples in different columns if you want to. You will then save this as a .txt file in excel.

[image: picture of example metadata map]

Once it is saved as a `.txt` file, you can import the map into R like so:

```
map <-import_qiime_sample_data("~/Path_to_your_metadata_map/Metadata_Map.txt")
```

And then you can merge your map with your `phyloseq` object:

```
new_phyloseq_object <- merge_phyloseq(old_phyloseq_object, map)
```

Then if you need to make any barplots or other figures later, you can call on the `Sample_Name` column you created. Like so:

```
bar_plot <- plot_bar(new_phyloseq_object, x="Sample_Name", fill="Genus")
```